# Facebook API share showing error "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on share functionality using `Facebook`. The login functionality is working fine. But when I try to share something using a sample code, it is showing like

> Sorry, something went wrong.
>
> We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

The code I am using is

```
$('#fb_test').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'This is the content of the "name" field.',
        link: 'URL which you would like to share ',
        picture: "URL of the image which is going to appear as thumbnail image in share dialogbox",
        caption: 'Caption like which appear as title of the dialog box',
        description: 'Small description of the post',
        message: ''
    }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead of yours this will works fine.

First reference this fb script after the **body** tag

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'app_id',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.8'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

then call this method on your `<a>` click:

```
function ShareOnFacebook(){
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: 'test Blog title',
link: 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
picture: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/740344950097903616/mORHo2rZ.jpg',
caption: 'I love stackoverflow',
description: 'The stackoverflow forum will provide good solutions',
message: ''
});
}
```

This will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this error can happen for any number of reasons, and they don't tell you what the problem is.

In my case, I omitted the # from the hashtag field, which is apparently cause for total failure.

```
win.FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href,
  hashtag: '#wow', // NOT 'wow'
})
```